# Horse racing simulator

Tags: python

I'm trying to make horse racing simulator, that makes strings add up randomly till they finish the max lenght, and i cannot seem to be able to do this correctly and i would like to have some assitance of what iam doing wrong with my currently provided code

```
import random
import os
from time import sleep

h1 = ''
h2 = ''
h3 = ''
h4 = ''
h5 = ''

while True: #len(h1) or len(h2) or len(h3) or len(h4) or len(h5) >= 15:
    os.system('clear')
    Horse_Select = random.choice((h1, h2, h3, h4, h5))
    Horse_Select += '='
    print(f'''{h1}
    {h2}
    {h3}
    {h4}
    {h5}''')
    sleep(0.5)
    #if len(h1) or len(h2) or len(h3) or len(h4) or len(h5) >= 15:
    #    break
    #else:
    #    continue
```

Comment: Please help us help you: What are you trying to achieve? What exactly is not working? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens? And what have you tried so far to solve the issue?

Comment: it should add = on the {hNUMBER} and print it, but it doesnt

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of random.choice. You seem to want to pick a variable randomly and then manipulate its value. But you are retrieving the value of that variable.

Comment: Oh i understand now, thank you, i'm still new to programming so mistakes do happen. Also the person below said i should use lists, thanks for the help.

Comment: The answer of Alex Hall is based on the same idea. Alex just also shows you an option how to solve this. Another option would be to use a dictionary, and pick the keys randomly. But a list or tuple seems the easiest way to do this. For the future, please always answer the questions I mentioned when posting here. Many times, this will even make you find the answer yourself. :)

Comment: Alright thanks for the tips, appreciate it!

Comment: For future reference, "it's not working" is not a question. It's a statement, and a poor one, for a Q&A site, at that. Instead, say what the code **does** do, and what you **expect** it to do **instead**. Then ask how you get it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't work like that. Put your horses in a list and choose a random index of the list.

```
import random
import os
from time import sleep

horses = ['', '', '', '', '']

while max(len(horse) for horse in horses) <= 15:
    os.system('clear')
    Horse_Select = random.choice(range(len(horses)))
    horses[Horse_Select] += '='
    print("\n".join(horses))
    sleep(0.5)
```

Spelled out to be closer to your code:

```
horses = ['', '', '']

while len(horses[0]) <= 15 and len(horses[1]) <= 15 and len(horses[2]) <= 15:
    os.system('clear')
    Horse_Select = random.choice([0, 1, 2])
    horses[Horse_Select] += '='
    print(horses[0])
    print(horses[1])
    print(horses[2])
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You can avoid checking all the lists all the time by checking only the one you just incremented and using `break`.

Comment: If you want to keep checking all horses, `while all(len(horse) <=15 for horse in horses)` looks better, I'd say :)